# Getting Computer Domain (Universal Windows Application)

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp

I am currently trying to pull the current users `Computer Domain` in a Universal Windows Application.

I do it like this in .Net:

```
public static string GetDomain()
{
    return Domain.GetComputerDomain().ToString();
}
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this in a Universal Windows Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the new 
[User.GetPropertiesAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn996552.aspx)

```
            IReadOnlyList<User> users = await User.FindAllAsync();
            foreach (User user in users)
            {
                string DomainName = (string)await user.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.DomainName);
            }
```